# Azure Continuous Deployment using tfs - Create new drop folder

Tags: azure, tfs, orchardcms

I have azure continuous deployment setup to deploy orchard solution through tfs online service. It is working fine. It deploys to azure cloud service - and resets the current instance. However, is it possible to deploy the build to a new folder each time in the same instance without resetting it. I assume we have to change the build template on tfs for this. Please advise if anyone has done this before. Thanks.